# One activity to another Activity, Dynamic Button Generation Using Array List

Tags: android, arraylist

I got an ArrayList with HashMap as Enumerator. Now the ArrayList is generating a data depends on that i need to generate Dynamic Buttons. The name of Button will be Present in the List. Hence i got the name using KEY and Value. But Dynamically Button is not Creating. Here is my code.
This is main activity oncreate Class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteraip);
    ed = et.getText();
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // when button is clicked the process will start
            free = ed.toString();
            url = "some url";
            Log.i(MESSAGE, "we got this string" + free);
            Log.i("The button got", url);
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewLight.class);
            in.putExtra(DATA,url);
            startActivity(in);
            }
    });
}
```

This is my viewLight class where i am generating dynamic Button based on Array List

```
public class ViewLight extends Activity {
public static final String msg = "ViewLightMain";
static final String KEY_LIGHTING = "Lighting";
static final String KEY_LID = "Light_Id";
static final String KEY_BID = "Box_Id";
static final String KEY_DID = "Device_Id";
static final String KEY_LN = "Light_Name";
static final String KEY_CT = "Control_Type";
static final String KEY_RM = "Room";
static final String KEY_STAT = "Status";
static final String KEY_CL = "Current_Level";
Button b;
String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_light);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    url = in.getStringExtra(MainActivity.DATA);
    Log.i(msg, url);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            XmlParser x = new XmlParser();
            String xml = x.Getaip(url);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> a = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            Document doc = x.getDom(xml);
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_LIGHTING);
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                HashMap< String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element)nl.item(i);
                h.put(KEY_LID,x.getValue(e,KEY_LID ));
                h.put(KEY_BID, x.getValue(e, KEY_BID));
                h.put(KEY_DID, x.getValue(e, KEY_DID));
                h.put(KEY_LN, x.getValue(e, KEY_LN));
                h.put(KEY_CT,x.getValue(e, KEY_CT));
                h.put(KEY_RM, x.getValue(e, KEY_RM));
                h.put(KEY_STAT, x.getValue(e, KEY_STAT));
                h.put(KEY_CL, x.getValue(e, KEY_CL));
                a.add(h);
                }
            Log.i(msg, "The arrayList is"+a.get(1));
            for (HashMap<String, String> arr : a) {
                for(Entry<String, String> ent: arr.entrySet()){
                    String key = ent.getKey();
                    String value = ent.getValue();
                    if(key.equals("Light_Name")){
                        Button b1 = new Button(ViewLight.this);
                        b1.setText(value);
                        l.addView(b1,lp);
                        Log.i("In FOr Loop", value);
                    }
                    Log.i(msg, "The key is"+key+"The value is"+value);

                }
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

The Program is working fine but i am unable to generate the buttons. The Screen Shots of the Output are here[image: MainActivity] [image: SecondActivity]  [image: AfterClickingButton]

After clicking that No Button is generating. Please Help me in regard.

Comment: Have you checked your logs or set breakpoints to see that your lists are in fact populated as you expect?

Comment: @codeMagic I am perfectly getting the lists what i want. My only problem is the button is not generating. remaining logic is working fine

Comment: @JDJ even after defining the setLayoutParams as you defined in the above.I am getting the Output.

Comment: I understand your buttons aren't generated but I asked because if the lists were empty then the loop would never be entered. Anyway, what orientation is your `main` `LinearLayout`? And is there any other views in it to start?

Comment: my orientation is vertical. loop has generated a output is correct. The print statement in loop is giving output, what i want.

Comment: i changed the manifest.xml, i removed the "maxsdkversion=18", as i am connecting to url without using AsyncTask.